# Variables not being printed from php while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a dropdown menu in a html form that calls a php file included below and it is getting to the while loop and judging from the echoes it seems to be executing correctly but it isn't returning the info.

To start with I just need the book column listed and I can increase the complexity once I can do this. My end goal is have book, author, genre and email listed.

The table has the format:
id-book-author-genre-email

Here is my PHP code:

```
 include('definitions.php');

 $con=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
 // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }
 $namequery="SELECT book,author,genre,email FROM book WHERE book = ?";
 $namestmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $namequery);

 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($namestmt, "s", $_POST['select1']);
 var_dump($_POST);

 mysqli_stmt_execute($namestmt);

 /* bind variables to prepared statement */
     mysqli_stmt_bind_result($namestmt, $name, $author, $genre, $email);

 while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($namestmt))
   {
   printf("%s %s %s %s\n", $name, $author, $genre, $email);
   echo "<br>";
   echo "got as far as the while loop";
   }

   /* close statement */
     mysqli_stmt_close($namestmt);


 /* close connection */
 mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

This returns:
array(1) { ["select1"]=> &string(4) "book" } (,) book author genre email 
got as far as the while loop (,) book author genre email 
got as far as the while loop (,) book author genre email 
got as far as the while loop

Any suggestions where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You do not bind the result to any variable. Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Comment: Are you saying I have the bind and execute in the wrong order? I'm sorry but I can't see what is wrong with my statement. Is there something I can add to mysqli_stmt_bind_param to maybe see the result of this to see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not certain you're correct there. In the select form in the original page I select book and I see there are 3 rows out of 9 that match and it prints out "got as far as the while loop" 3 times. If that were wrong surely there would be nothing passed to mysqli_stmt_fetch and I wouldn't get that printed out.

Comment: You are binding the params but not the result. For that you have to call mysqli_stmt_bind_result(). mysqli_stmt_fetch returns a bool and not an array. That was the way the old mysql functions did it.

Comment: Hopefully I've made the changes correctly above but still having problems. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you define the variables before the binding? Also it is always smart to run the query from the mysql client to see whether it gives a result. Is the where clause book = 'book' correct?

Comment: SELECT book, author, genre, email
FROM book
WHERE book =  'book' has 3 results. I'm a bit confused how I can define the variables. I thought I was defining 4 variables in mysqli_stmt_bind_result as there were 4 columns in the select statement. Is $col1 a special identifier to identify the first column in the table etc. Thanks and apologies if I'm still confusing things.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. Have it working now. It was the $col1 etc I had the problems. Appreciate your help.